# find pairs of elements that satisfy certain property

Tags: python, list, algorithm

If an input [s1, ..., sn] is given, and a property P is also given, the program should output the consecutive pairs that satisfy this P.

For example, if P is that the sum of two elements in the pair should be less than 20, then input `[1,10,29,17]` should output `[(1,10)]` since it is the only consecutive pair that satisfy this P.

For simplicity let's say checking the property P is constant time. A easy solution is the loop through the list so that it is O(n).

For example in python

```py
def f(ls, P: callable):
    r = []
    for i in range(len(ls)-1):
        if P(ls[i], ls[i+1]):
            r.append((ls[i], ls[i+1]))
    return r

assert f([1,10,29,17], lambda x, y: x+y<=20) == [(1,10)]
assert f([1,10,29,17], lambda x, y: x < y) == [(1,10),(10,29)] # checking if first is smaller than the second
```

But I am wondering if there are some methods that can speed up this process. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are not.  Since you've left both the sequences and the properties as abstract entities, there is no inherent information we can utilize to avoid the basic requirement: we have to check every element in the list.  This makes **O(N)** the theoretical minimum.